# How to make my desktop select list behave like a ios picker when viewed on iphone?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown list like this:
[image]

Can I make it behave like this when viewed on iphone?

[image]

I'm using bootstrap 3, any suggestions??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No you can not automatically create a Select field in Desktop like on iOS because the select field on mobile uses the native mobile OS implementation. So Bootstrap won't help you here at this point.

Long answer: You could try to recreate the select field on desktop with CSS and JavaScript.
jQuery UI Selectmenu (https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) allows you to create custom select dropdown fields which you could style via CSS.

Comment: You mean style it like a ios picker when viewed on iphone??

Comment: Exactly. You also have to implement the scroll behaviour via JavaScript